# how to pass an event to a variable using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My **javascript** code

```
function drag(ev){  
    var x= ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}
```

I need this event to pass in a variable,so that I need to do some action. How to do this please help me. When I pass this its not working fine. it will be very helpful for my project to do. Please help me for this code. If you have any  idea to do it on another way tell me that too

I need pass this variable to another function .

Comment: If you "need pass this variable to another function", change the scope of that variable or call the function from that function using `newFunction(x)`

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you're asking, you're looking for something like this:

```
function drag(ev){
    var x= ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
    otherfunc(ev);    
}

function otherfunc(ev){
  // Do something with ev
}
```

Comment: its not working . what my concept is while i drag that image i have to store that image in the variable ... so i need that event to store in a variable

Comment: @Bhargavi how do you drag? with jquery drag?

Comment: Are you looKing for `otherfunc(ev.target)`?

Answer (score 0):

Change the scope of the variable

```
var x;
function drag(ev){  
    x = ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

//now do whatever you want with x variable, e.g.
x++;

function outputX() {
    alert(x); // here it will also work
}
```

In your example x variable scope was within the function. It means the variable was *dead* outside the function.